# Global minimum of multivariable function with monotone increasing partial derivative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

Given a multivariable function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ and assume that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ are monotone increasing with respect to $x_i$. This means the diagonal of Hessian matrix are positive. I wonder if there are more than one isolate local minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Here there are two examples.

1. Consider the function
   $$f(x,y)=(x+y)^2$$
   then $f_x(x,y)=f_y(x,y)=2(x+y)$ are both increasing with respect $x$ and $y$, but $f$ has infinite minimum points (not isolated) along the line $y=-x$.
2. For two isolated local minumum points, consider the function
   $$f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)$$
   which attains its minimum value $0$ at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.
   It is easy to verify that
   $$f_{xx}(x,y)=2((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)+8x(x-1)+2(x^2+y^2)=3(2x-1)^2+(2y-1)^2\geq 0$$
   which implies that $f_x$ is increasing. By symmetry we find that $f_y$ is increasing too.

Comment: But the minimum points are not isolated.

Comment: @ganyao Now you have also an example with two isolated minimum points